# Allman-style anonymous classes

Tags: java, coding-style, anonymous-class

Any recommendations on how to use anonymous classes while staying consistent with [Allman indent style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style)? I don't really like anything I've come up with, e.g.

```
// Pass as parameter.
foo(new Clazz( )
    {
       // Do stuff.
    });

// Assign to variable.
Clazz bar = new Clazz( )
            {
               // Do stuff.
            };
```

Comment: whats wrong with what you have posted?  why don't you like it?

Comment: Line terminators end up in arbitrary positions, and brackets aren't vertically aligned (the parentheses enclosing the method call's arguments, for example), which defeats the purpose of Allman style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've settled on.

```
Foo foo = new Foo()
{
    // Do stuff.
};
```

And I just don't define anonymous classes inside method calls anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The best compromise I came up with for my own code, is indenting the anonymous class a single tabbing level, and putting the closing parentheses on a new line.

```
// Pass as parameter.
foo(new Clazz( )
    {
       // Do stuff.
    }
);

void func () {
    foo(new Clazz( )
        {
           // Do stuff.
        }
    );
}

// Assign to variable.
Clazz bar = new Clazz( )
    {
        // Do stuff.
    };
```

Comment: Doesn't really do it for me. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Allman style is really about aligning the {braces}, not all the (brackets). I suppose you are free to do both if you want, but it looks like a source of problems (like this one) to me, without a clear payback in readability. In other words, a logical fetish :-)

You could follow the guide at http://mbreen.com/javastyle.html:
"A statement containing a declaration with a code block is indented first as a statement." I think that would change your examples to

```
foo (new Clazz( )
    {
        // Do stuff.
    });

Clazz bar = (
    new Clazz( )
    {
        // Do stuff.
    });
```